# Checking passed object existence in Laravel delayed queue job

Tags: laravel, eloquent, queue, jobs

I believe if I pass an Eloquent object to a delayed Laravel job a "findOrFail" method is called to "restore" the object and pass it to the controller of my Job class.

The problem is that the DB record representing the object might be gone by the time the job is actually processed.

So "findOrFail" aborts before even calling the "handle" methods.

Everything seems fine. The problem is that the job now "gets transferred" to the failed jobs list. I know I can remove it from there manually, but that doesn't sound right.

Is there a way to "know" in my job class directly that the passed object "failed to load" or "does not exist" or anything similar?

Basically I would like to be able to do something if "ModelNotFoundException" is thrown while "rebuilding" my passed objects.

Thank you

**SOLUTION:**

Based on Yauheni Prakopchyk's answer I wrote my own trait and used it instead of SerializesModels where I need my altered behaviour.

Here's my new trait:

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Database\ModelIdentifier;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;

trait SerializesNullableModels
{
    use SerializesModels {
        SerializesModels::getRestoredPropertyValue as parentGetRestoredPropertyValue;
    }

    protected function getRestoredPropertyValue($value)
    {
        try
        {
            return $this->parentGetRestoredPropertyValue($value);
        }
        catch (ModelNotFoundException $e)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

And that's it - now if the model loading fails I still get a null and can decide what to do with it in my handle method.
And if this is only needed in a job class or two I can keep using original trait everywhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i'm not mistaken, you have to override `getRestoredPropertyValue` in your job class.

```
protected function getRestoredPropertyValue($value)
{
    try{
        return $value instanceof ModelIdentifier
            ? (new $value->class)->findOrFail($value->id) : $value;
    }catch(ModelNotFoundException $e) {
        // Your handling code;
    }
    exit;
}
```

Comment: This seems to work. In the "catch" part I simply return null and then decide what to do in my handle method.

Comment: What would be the best practice to have this in my app? Extend Job class with overwritten method,  call it "NullableJob" or something and extend it when I want this behaviour?

Comment: Extending did not work since the method comes from a trait. I simply wrote a new trait which overrides the method and used in instead. Will put the details at the end of my question. Thank you!

Comment: @MaGnetas Being late, nothing i can add to your answer. :3

Comment: Check this out - I even made an alias of "original trait" method and used it. So even if the method changes in the future my new trait will still work. Thanx again.